# How to open an Image in new activity when clicked in viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm using viewpager to display the slideshow of the images but when I'm clicked on any one of the image it need to opened in new activity. Can anyone help me?

**I'm displaying toast message when clicked on image but my actually requirement is to open the image in new activity.**

The code is below:

```
class MyCustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
private Context context;
private int images[];
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public int i;

MyCustomPagerAdapter(Context context, int images[]) {
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.full_profile, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandedImage);
    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

    container.addView(itemView);

    //listening to image click
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Toast.makeText(context, "you clicked image " + (position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ImageOpeningActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MY_IMAGE", images[position]);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

}

ImageOpeningActivity.class

```
class ImageOpeningActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imageopening);



    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

    if(getIntent()!=null){
        int image  = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("MY_IMAGE");
        imageView.setImageResource(image);
    }
}
```

}

although i changed my code i getting an error, the error is below.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.vmax.kalyanam/com.vmax.kalyanam.ImageOpeningActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.vmax.kalyanam.ImageOpeningActivity> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>

public class Full_profile extends Activity {
Toolbar toolbar;
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
//public String title = "KANDIBANDA ROJA";


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_profile);


    ViewPager viewPager;
    int images[] = {
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.one
    };

    MyCustomPagerAdapter myCustomPagerAdapter;
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    myCustomPagerAdapter = new MyCustomPagerAdapter(Full_profile.this, images);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myCustomPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: what is your problem in it ? do you want to know only way ? or do you want to know how to move image with the opening activity ?

Comment: i'm using viewpager in my application and displaying the position of the image when clicked on it, but my requirement is open the image in new activity not to display the toast

Comment: check out my answer

Comment: @SharartiKAKA check my code i'm changed it but also i'm getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put intent here in "listening to image click"

```
      imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(this,PhotoViewerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image", imageurl);
    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



public class PhotoViewerActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 


        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
     // you can show image from url using library like glide or picasso
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_photo_viewer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        PhotoViewerActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all do this in your code instead of Toast. Comment out Toast and paste these lines.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageOpeningActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MY_IMAGE", images[position]);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

step2: Create activity with the name of ImageOpeningActivity  and in its xml take a Imageview , let suppose its Id is myImageView  then do following in your on create

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

    if(getIntent()!=null){
        int image  = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("MY_IMAGE");
        imageView.setImageResource(image);
    }
```

I am supposing that your images[position] is integer array.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.vmax.kalyanam/com.vmax.kalyanam.ImageOpeningActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.vmax.kalyanam.ImageOpeningActivity> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>

Comment: you need to post code of your adapter of view pager then I can look into this matter

Comment: let me check it

Comment: there is nothing wrong in the code. just add public with your activity class name . 
e.g    public class ImageOpeningActivity extends AppCompatActivity { .....

Answer (score 0):

create new activity with imageview in xml layout and call this from your viewpager image onclick

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageDetailActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("image",images[i]);
startActivity(intent);
```

ImageDetailActivity.java

```
    public class ImageDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


     Drawable imageDrawable;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_detail);



          Intent intent =  getIntent();
              imageDrawable=   getResources().getDrawable(intent.getIntExtra("image",-1)); 
            imageView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
        }   

    }
```

Make sure you add this ImageDetailActivity to your android manifest file

Comment: i need to open the image using position

Comment: you can send the data from string imgeurl = images[position]. I dont know the images are urls or drawables.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.vmax.kalyanam/com.vmax.kalyanam.ImageOpeni‌​ngActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.vmax.kalyanam.ImageOpeningActivity> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation> –

Answer (score 0):

Like @Pratap said you can send image url from one activity to another. But if you wanted to pass image itself as bitmap follow this method. 
Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you can pass it as intent extra.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it in ImageDetailActivity by calling,

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

**Warning: Do not pass data more than 500Kb through Intent** [Refer this site](https://www.neotechsoftware.com/blog/android-intent-size-limit)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply with **loading from URL**... follow below steps:

**Step-1**: In your **adapter.java** class

First add click listener to your view/image which you want to open in a new activity... In this Im taking image example to open in new activity.

```
//Set Event Click
    view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent new_intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
        new_intent.putExtra("currentImg", imgList.get(position).getImage());
        context.startActivity(new_intent);
    });
```

In the above code, you will see this code: `new_intent.putExtra("currentImg", imgList.get(position).getImage());` here **imgList** is your image array list, put your **listArray** name & rest is same as give code.

**Step-2**: In **YourActivity.class**, which is your other activity where you want to show that image.

Initiate your **imageView** what you have created in **activity_your.xml** file

example: `ImageView image;`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your);

    image = findViewById(R.id.image);

    //Gif Url from myAdapter
    String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("currentImg");

    //Set Image
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(image);
}
```

Here, you can display your image using any imageLibraray picasso/glide etc. I used glide in this example.